# Jquery - Change css class size position on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, jquery-animate

Allright hi there guys.

I just started working on my portfolio and wanted to add some cool looking animations. I'm completely new to jquery so i'm spending a lot of time looking around for the right functions. However i'm stuck at the part where i want to make my 'welcome part' move up to the top of the screen when i slightly scroll down, where i show my name and the nav part. And when i scroll up everything goes down to the center into that tiny little 'welcome' div. Hope you see where i'm getting at.

Jsfiddle here

`Jsfiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/a2fL7kq3/3/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for. Do you want to hide the extra links? You can use the `overflow: hidden` css rule to achieve that. 

If you want to dissect and recreate how the inspiration site does it, look at the `<ng-hello interval="60" class="navigator" style="opacity: 1;">` tag in Developer Tools (or your browser's equivalent). As you scroll up and down, you'll see that he adds/removes a `navigation` class to the tag. You should check out the css styles that are added to and removed from to child elements when the `navigation` class is added/removed.

Comment: Animations, how to, what to use. Look a the inspiration link, thats kind off what i want. I dont know how to switch classes properly without the position bugging out. Links were a placeholder since the classes (icons) wont work at jsfiddle. Sorry if i'm not being clear enough haha.

Comment: You can change classes for the header with the following code: http://pastebin.com/xb7Ddf8D. It could replace the section with the `.animate()` calls. However, you will still have to write the css to perform the desired behavior. For this, you can look at the `ng-hello` and `ng-hello.navigator` styles on the website you linked. For example, the transition he uses is `transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.23,1,.32,1);`.

Comment: I'm super late but thanks for that! It was a push in the right direction. Playing with the animations whenever i have some time left, i love it. Thanks!